# Take your child to work day

Tags: workplace-rhythm

In the US there is a practice originally called "Take your Daughter to work day". It has recently been renamed "Take your child to work day".

The original idea  was to show daughters that there was a world of work beyond secretaries, nurses, and teachers. By inviting sons to work it has changed the dynamic.

Is there still a benefit for any of the parties concerned -- that is employers, employees, and especially kids -- in doing this?

Could anyone enlighten me as to the benefits of doing this to all the parties concerned?

This is not related to the general question: [What benefits are there of being allowed to take your kids to work?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/481/take-your-kids-to-work).

Comment: exact same question here http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/481/take-your-kids-to-work why ask again?

Comment: @bretterer The assumption the part of the people who answered was that it wasn't to participate in "Take your kid to work day", which is employer sponsored but just take your kid with you for other reasons.  Hence the second question.

Comment: Rather than having the *"This may be related to Take your kids to work? question"* bit on top, it'd be more useful if you explained, in the question text rather than comments, what the relationship between the questions is and how this question is *different* from that one.  Also more specifics would help: what kind of work environment is it? Has anyone actually brought kids to work? How is it organized? What age kids? The answers will depend on all this - without specifics you'll get either nothing or a long list of options.

Comment: I think these two questions need better disambiguation - especially as the answers on the other are kind of mixed. One is "taking you kids to work one time as work experience", the other is "taking you kids to work because there's no one else to look after them". Very different.

Comment: I have reworked the question to be about "Take your Daughter to work day" or course the edits are waiting for peer review because I have less then 200 points

Comment: I have closed this question as Not Constructive.  There was an attempt to distinguish it from [the other question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/481/take-your-kids-to-work). It is still very difficult to see the difference, but more importantly, both questions are not constructive as they are worded.  If we have any clever editors perhaps we can get these in better shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the message has been lost. The idea was to encourage girls to pursue education because of all jobs they could get if they went to college.

In many places it is just an open house day, to show families what their parent does at work.

When done correctly the payoff is not immediate, the young girls that are inspired are not ready to enter the work force for another 10 years. Plus this is not recruiting them to work for you, so they probably end up working for somebody else.

Comment: 'Take your Daughter to work day' conveyed the message that female kids are inferior and need their own 'special day' in order to have a chance against those mean boyz.  

OTH 'take your kid to work day' treats boys and girls as equals and is probably a good way for kids to better understand their parents.